# How to convert BTreeSet to BTreeMap?

Tags: rust

I have a `BTreeSet` object and I want to convert it into a `BTreeMap` with default indices (i.e., starting from 0 and incrementing). More precisely, given this:

```
let set = BTreeSet::from([0, 2, 4, 6, 8]);
```

I want to end up with `BTreeMap<usize, usize>` that holds `[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8)]`. I can do it with a loop for example as

```
let mut tree = BTreeMap::new();
for (i, v) in set.clone().into_iter().enumerate() {
    tree.insert(i, v);
}
```

But is there any shortcut (i.e., one line code) that does the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there any shortcut (i.e., one line code) that does the same?

```rust
let map = set.iter().copied().enumerate().collect::<BTreeMap<_, _>>();
println!("{:?}", map);
```

```
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8}
```

tho note that this is a `BTreeMap<usize, i32>`, because `i32` is the default resolution for `{integer}` literals if they're otherwise unconstrained, which is the case here.